# How to type annotate a closure that captures a function parameter

Tags: generics, rust, annotations

I have this code:

```rust
use std::iter::TakeWhile;

pub trait Until<T, P>: Iterator<Item = T>
where
    P: FnMut(&T) -> bool,
    Self: Sized,
{
    fn until<'a>(self, f: P) -> TakeWhile<Self, fn(&'a T) -> bool> {
        self.take_while((move |item| !f(item)) as fn(&'a T) -> bool)
    }
}

impl<T, P, I> Until<T, P> for I
where
    P: FnMut(&T) -> bool,
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
}
```

Which does not compile with this error:

```
   Compiling until v0.1.0 (/home/rne/until)
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `[closure@src/lib.rs:9:26: 9:37]` as `fn(&'a T) -> bool`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:25
  |
9 |         self.take_while((move |item| !f(item)) as fn(&'a T) -> bool)
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invalid cast

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0605`.
error: could not compile `until` due to previous error
```

If I leave out the explicit cast:

```rust
use std::iter::TakeWhile;

pub trait Until<T, P>: Iterator<Item = T>
where
    P: FnMut(&T) -> bool,
    Self: Sized,
{
    fn until<'a>(self, f: P) -> TakeWhile<Self, fn(&'a T) -> bool> {
        self.take_while(move |item| !f(item))
    }
}

impl<T, P, I> Until<T, P> for I
where
    P: FnMut(&T) -> bool,
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> src/lib.rs:9:25
     |
9    |         self.take_while(move |item| !f(item))
     |              ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found closure
     |              |
     |              arguments to this function are incorrect
     |
     = note: expected fn pointer `fn(&T) -> bool`
                   found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:9:25: 9:36]`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
    --> src/lib.rs:9:38
     |
9    |         self.take_while(move |item| !f(item))
     |                                      ^ `f` captured here
note: associated function defined here
    --> /usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:1204:8
     |
1204 |     fn take_while<P>(self, predicate: P) -> TakeWhile<Self, P>
     |        ^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `until` due to previous error
```

How do I properly specify the type of the returned function in the `TakeWhile` return type?
Note: I do not want to use `Box` with a `dyn <Trait>` content, but pure generics.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that on nightly, using the [`return_position_impl_trait_in_trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) feature:

```rust
#![feature(return_position_impl_trait_in_trait)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]

pub trait Until<T, P>: Iterator<Item = T>
where
    P: FnMut(&T) -> bool,
    Self: Sized,
{
    fn until<'a>(self, mut f: P) -> TakeWhile<Self, impl FnMut(&'a T) -> bool> {
        self.take_while(move |item| !f(item))
    }
}
```

If, and only if, the callback (`P`) is zero sized, i.e. captures nothing, you can use `unsafe` code to create a fake instance of it on stable:

```rust
fn until(self, _f: P) -> TakeWhile<Self, fn(&T) -> bool> {
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<P>(), 0, "`P` must be a ZST");
    self.take_while(move |item| {
        // SAFETY: `P` is zero-sized, so all-zeroes bit pattern is valid for it.
        let mut f = unsafe { std::mem::zeroed::<P>() };
        !f(item)
    })
}
```

But at this point, I'd instead create a custom iterator adapter instead of using `take_while()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I seem to stumble over the issue again and again, that you can not yet use `impl Trait` as parameter or return types in traits. And I cannot understand for the life of me why type annotating a capturing closure is not supported in Rust.

Comment: @RichardNeumann It is supported, on nightly (with `type_alias_impl_trait` or `return_position_impl_trait_in_trait`). And on inherent methods.

Comment: Yeah. I was of course referring to *stable*. But thanks for the clarification.